# How to find the location of log4j,xml?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, log4j

How to find the location of log4j.xml?

I need to insert the location of my log4j.xml in the below code

```
URL u = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("");
DOMConfigurator.configure(u);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named log4j2.xml (not log4j.xml) in the classpath.

You can also specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

For more info please click [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html)